# Elastic Beanstalk returning error - Gradle/Java Application

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, gradle, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to upload a new Java Application on AWS using Elastic Beanstalk and RDS, I've tested the build and WAR file locally and its working fine, how can i solve this problem? I'm new to uploading Java apps to AWS.

[image: Elastic Beanstalk Events]

**Here is the log**

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1O1g4HUQDR7aVdRLWJ0aUw1bkU

Comment: Please post the contents of `/var/log/eb-activity.log`, as the error suggests. You can do this either via `eb logs` on the command line, `eb ssh` followed by `cat /var/log/eb-activity.log`, or the "Logs" pane in the EB console. Also please make sure to post the log contents as text and not a screenshot.

Comment: @Brian i added the log

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the script the [bootRepackage task](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.10.RELEASE/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html#build-tool-plugins-gradle-repackage-configuration) prepend in the jar. My solution was to create an empty file and set:

```
bootRepackage {
    embeddedLaunchScript = file("nope.script")
}
```

It's definitely not the fanciest solution, but as a temporary one, works like a charm.